# БачкИ или бАчки?

Tags: фонетика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно ставить ударение в слове "бачки" (в смысле, маленькие бакенбарды)? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На первый слог. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%E1%E0%F7%EA%E8

Comment: В одной невероятной скачке
     Вы прожили свой краткий век
     И ваши кудри, ваши бачки
     И ваши кудри, ваши бачки
     Засыпал снег